# In-memory SQLite database isn't cleared after ASP .NET Core integration tests

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I'm writing integrations tests for an ASP .NET Core WebApi, using a WebApplicationFactory that will replace the DbContext by an SQLite in memory one :

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext Context { get; private set; }
        private readonly string connectionString = "DataSource=:memory:";
        private readonly SqliteConnection connection;

        public CustomWebApplicationFactory()
        {
            connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_SECRET","L*$w56jr!XZQZ$CFNQ7w$bM&@oDQccNX4Um4RpKhtMQLhzRWM^fo$MGgoEPoSCrmonNn6pBqePLC&kTyb6@KcWd3U%zRftyVzQvJSMZW*QAg3!kHh&gD8zR7w6yGrS64");
            builder.UseEnvironment("Development");
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType ==
                         typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>));

                services.Remove(descriptor);
                // Create a new service provider.
                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                // Add a database context (AppDbContext) using an in-memory database for testing.
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlite(connection);
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
                });

                // Build the service provider.
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database contexts
                var scope = sp.CreateScope();
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var appDb = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                Context = appDb;
            });
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            this.connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

And in my test class constructor, which I expect to be called for each test case, I do the following to empty the database between each test case :

```cs
        public IntegrationTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory factory)
        {
            this.client = factory.CreateClient();
            this.db = factory.Context;
            factory.Context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            factory.Context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
```

However, the data seems to be persistent between test cases. What would be the proper way to deal with this problem ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: With an in-memory SQLite database you *don't* need to clear the database. Nothing is persisted to disk. If you only used `AddDbContext` the database would be removed when the DbContext was disposed. You're explicitly creating a Db Instance that will stay alive as long as the factory exists though, and even create a scope that never goes out of scope in `ConfigureWebHost`. If you use the same factory instance in all test cases, the database will never be cleared

Comment: I hope that `JWT_SECRET` is not something that should have stayed a secret. If it is, then you better go change that wherever you use it.

Comment: Why were `connection` and `Context = appDb;` added? Did you find out that the database disappeared after each request, and wanted to keep it around for multiple requests? To do that, pass the database *from the outside* so the test code controls when the connection is created or closed. Pass it as a parameter to the `CustomWebApplicationFactory` constructor and open it from the test code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I understand you well, I should not reference the `Context` in the `WebApplicationFactory` ? How should I then acquire it in my tests to setup testing data ?
@Xerillio no it is only used for testing purpose, that's why I didn't bother to redact it, but thank you for the alert !

Comment: @Ombrelin you shouldn't create the connection in the `WebApplicationFactory`. The database remains active as long as that connection is open, which is at least as long as `factory` is active. Unless you  override `Dispose` in the factory to close the connection, it will remain active until the factory is garbage collected

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried with a `connection.Close()` in the `Dispose()` (see edit in post) but the result is the same